# How to stop python pdb from restarting after completion of script

Tags: python, pdb

This is the content of myfile.py

```
print('1st line')
print('2nd line')
print('3rd Line')
print('4th Line')
print('5th Line')
```

This is the my pdb command:
`python3 -mpdb -c "b 2" -c c myfile.py`

This is what the output is when i run it:

```
Breakpoint 1 at /Users/rahulbadenkal/Desktop/Personal/python-in-a-box/myfile.py:2
1st line
> /Users/rahulbadenkal/Desktop/Personal/python-in-a-box/myfile.py(2)<module>()
-> print('2nd line')
(Pdb)
```

Then I enter the command 'c' to the shell and this is the output:

```
Breakpoint 1 at /Users/rahulbadenkal/Desktop/Personal/python-in-a-box/myfile.py:2
1st line
> /Users/rahulbadenkal/Desktop/Personal/python-in-a-box/myfile.py(2)<module>()
-> print('2nd line')
(Pdb) c
2nd line
3rd Line
4th Line
5th Line
The program finished and will be restarted
> /Users/rahulbadenkal/Desktop/Personal/python-in-a-box/myfile.py(1)<module>()
-> print('1st line')
(Pdb)
```

As you can see the debugging session restarts after the whole script is executed. I know I can type 'q' in to the shell to close the pdb session. But is it possible to tell pdb at the start (in  the `python3 -mpdb -c "b 2" -c c myfile.py` command) to auto close session once the program is completed and not restart? Need to do this as I am passing the commands programatically and I have no way of knowing when the script is actually completed.